# Use formula to dynamically modify named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I am using a bunch of named ranges in a workbook.  Here is the history of how it has changed to make it more dynamic for when they ask me to modify it.

What I want to do is search the A column from 1 to 100 for the label in the A column (that I code into the named range formula) and where it finds it, the named range will know is the row.  I know I will still need to update the named range if we ever change the name of a row but I would only need to update one named range as opposed to 75-100 named ranges as I do now whenever we make a change.

**Here is the current Named Range that I am using:**

```
=INDIRECT("Input!$C$23:"LastColumn&"$23")
```

LastColumn is a named range that contains the letter of the last column.

**Here is some history on why I do it this way:**

When I first created it I referenced the cells directly in formulas (no named range) and had to change all the formulas whenever I added another row, column, etc.  Then I switched it to Named References.  This fixed it so whenever we added a row, I did not need to change the references at all.  However, I still had to change all the references whenever we changed the amount of columns.  What I did was make the columns variable, so if we change the amount of columns I don't have to make any changes to the named ranges.  Unfortunately, this had the unintended consequences of making it so whenever I add, remove, or move a row I need to update all the references.  Now, I have an idea that will make both the rows and the columns variable.  So, I can make any change without having to update any references.

I needed to do it this way because most of the time the columns will be empty and I do not know when they will have data in them.

Comment: TL;DR. Please read [ask]. Create a simple MCVE, ask a simple question.

Comment: @Amit, the question is simple - the rest is the reasoning of why I need to do this.  I made it easier though to distinguish between the question and the history.

Comment: What row ALWAYS contains the correct amount of non-blank entries and does it contain numbers or text? Example: a header row would always have entries to the extents of the data matrix while the data rows may or may not contain blanks in the last column.

Comment: @Jeeped

none.  I have no problem with the columns.  I need to make the rows dynamic now.  The columns already are dynamic.

Comment: Far be it from me to suggest a better method that would accomplish both tasks in a more efficient manner. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Jeeped, sorry I was not complaining. I thought you were confused with my question.  Thank you for trying to help and hope you did not take it offensively because that is not how I meant it.

 I do not know if I can modify the way I do the columns because no row will always have the correct amount of non-blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

Abandon the volatile [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) and use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) for the termination of the range with [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) locating the last column. The row can be determined by a MATCH on column A to "Label".

As I understand it, you want to locate "Label" in column A and have its location define the row in `=INDIRECT("Input!$C$23:"LastColumn&"$23")` where 23 currently defines the row.

Abandoning INDIRECT, the `Input!$C$23` reference can be changed to:

```
=INDEX(Input!$C:$C, MATCH("Label", Input!$A:$A, 0))
```

So all that is left is to find the last column. There must be *something* on that worksheet that can be used to locate the last column regardless of column deletions or additions but I will just use the last value in the row that contains "Label" in column A.

```
'this finds the last text value in row 23
=MATCH("zzz", Input!23:23)
'this finds the last number or date value in row 23
=MATCH(1e99, Input!23:23)
'since I do not know whether *the row* (e.g. 23:23) contains text, numbers, dates 
'or a combination of any of those, I will have to double up the formula and add error control
=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz", Input!23:23), 0), IFERROR(MATCH(1e99, Input!23:23), 0))
```

You can stitch two INDEX functions together with a colon just as if you were typing C23:Z23.

```
=INDEX(Input!$C:$C, MATCH("Label", Input!$A:$A, 0)):INDEX(Input!$A:$ZZ,MATCH("Label",Input!$A:$A,0),MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99, INDEX(Input!$A:$ZZ,MATCH("Label",Input!$A:$A,0),0)),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",INDEX(Input!$A:$ZZ,MATCH("Label",Input!$A:$A,0),0)),0)))
```

Yes, it looks complicated but a lot of that comes from not knowing whether the row in question contains text or numbers and it does less work than a volatile INDIRECT (which recalculates whenever anything in the entire workbook changes) while remaining up-to-date despite row and column deletion/insertions.

BTW, when using text-as-cell-references within INDIRECT there is no need to use the $ absolute reference indicator. An address-as-text is a text string; it will not change no matter what you do to it short of retyping it. The above method *does* require absolute cell referencing as it is using actual cell and cell range references.

Comment: Sorry the first column will always be text, never numbers. 

I appreciate your help.  thank you again :)

Comment: Jeeped, how would I simplify it?  the first column will always be text.